# Npm publish latest

Tags: npm, npm-publish

I published a new version of my package (0.3.2) but it is not the latest one.

`npm view` give me:

```
{
 'dist-tags': { latest: 0.3.1}
 versions: [..., 0.3.2],
 time: {..., '0.3.2': '2016-...'},
 version: '0.3.1',
 ...
}
```

I get an NPM error:
"You cannot publish over the previously published version 0.3.2"

Answer (score 0):

Because i didn't use `npm publish (--tag latest)` but `npm publish --tag pkg@0.3.2`, my version 0.3.2 is freezed on the NPM registry without being the latest one. NPM does not have any way to rollback, the only workaroud is to bump the version (0.3.3 in my case).